# TeamCity: use multiple values for environment variable

Tags: build, teamcity, environment

I'd like to run a build with different values for a specific environment variable.

I know that Jenkins alows this with its "matrix" builds, where you define a set of env variables and it builds the project with all the combinations of these variables:

2 variables:

```
TARGET = X86, X64
DEBUG  = 0,   1
```

Will produce 4 builds:

```
        | X86 | X64 |
DEBUG 0 |  X  |  X  |
DEBUG 1 |  X  |  X  |
```

I didn't find the option in TC, apart from copy/paste a build conf and modify by hand the environment variable.

Is this possible in teamcity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no existing option for that in TeamCity (as of TeamCity 8.0.1).

Your options here are:

- create a base build configuration template and 4 build configurations which inherit from this template with different setting for environment variables
- use a manual triggering of the builds, but alter the value of the environment variable on build start (use Run custom build dialog for this)
- write a custom TeamCity plugin which would allow to run a bunch of builds with appropriate variables set

  Regards,
  KIR